# d3 animate path by arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I started to work with d3. And have a question, how can I animate properly triangle along the filling path? I created a base for the gauge chart and animated it.

```js
var chart = d3.select("#speedometer");

const arc = d3
    .arc()
    .outerRadius(120)
    .innerRadius(90)
    .startAngle(-Math.PI / 2);

chart
    .append("path")
    .datum({
        endAngle: Math.PI / 2
    })
    .attr("transform", "translate(160, 180)")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .style("fill", "#495270")
    .attr("d", arc);

const triangle = chart
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(30, 180) rotate(90)')
.style('width', '100%')
.append("path").attr("d", "M3.937,0,7.873,14H0Z");

const newAngle = (70 / 100) * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;

const foreground = chart
    .append("path")
    .datum({ endAngle: -Math.PI / 2 })
    .style("fill", "rgb(50, 188, 228)")
    .attr("transform", "translate(160, 180)")
    .attr("d", arc);

foreground
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
        return function (t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return arc(d);
        };
    });

triangle
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)

function pathTween(path) {
    const length = path.node().getTotalLength(); // Get the length of the path
    const r = d3.interpolate(0, length); // Set up interpolation from 0 to the path length
    return function (t) {
        const point = path.node().getPointAtLength(r(t)); // Get the next point along the path
        d3
            .select(this) // Select the circle
            .attr("transform", `translate(${point.x}, ${point.y})`);
    };
}
```

```css
.main-wrapper{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.element{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.title{
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.description{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#speedometer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

canvas{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <section class="ui-section">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="title">
        Speedometr
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <svg id="speedometer" viewbox="0 0 300 300"></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

The question is, how can I link the triangle to the edge of the animating arc like in the picture?

I know I should use

```
tween('path'....)
```

but not sure

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use SVG [transform: rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform), because it allows you to specify relative to what you should rotate, and because you can chain transformations. In this case, I transform the angle to the centre of the arc, then rotate it into the right direction, and then move it up a little bit more than the outer radius so it follows the line smoothly.

It's not pixel perfect, which I think is because the triangle is not a whole number of pixels wide.

```js
var chart = d3.select("#speedometer");

const arc = d3
    .arc()
    .outerRadius(120)
    .innerRadius(90)
    .startAngle(-Math.PI / 2);

chart
    .append("path")
    .datum({
        endAngle: Math.PI / 2
    })
    .attr("transform", "translate(160, 180)")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .style("fill", "#495270")
    .attr("d", arc);

const triangle = chart
  .append('g')
  .datum({ endAngle: -Math.PI / 2 })
  .style('width', '100%')
  .append("path").attr("d", "M3.937,0,7.873,14H0Z");

const newAngle = (70 / 100) * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;

const foreground = chart
    .append("path")
    .datum({ endAngle: -Math.PI / 2 })
    .style("fill", "rgb(50, 188, 228)")
    .attr("transform", "translate(160, 180)")
    .attr("d", arc);

foreground
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
        return function (t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return arc(d);
        };
    });

triangle
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attrTween("transform", function (d) {
        const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
        return function (t) {
          const angleRadians = interpolate(t);
          const angleDegrees = 360 * angleRadians / (2 * Math.PI);
          return `
            translate(158 176)
            rotate(${angleDegrees + 180} 3.5 7)
            translate(0 132)
          `;
        };
    });

function pathTween(path) {
    const length = path.node().getTotalLength(); // Get the length of the path
    const r = d3.interpolate(0, length); // Set up interpolation from 0 to the path length
    return function (t) {
        const point = path.node().getPointAtLength(r(t)); // Get the next point along the path
        d3
            .select(this) // Select the circle
            .attr("transform", `translate(${point.x}, ${point.y})`);
    };
}
```

```css
.main-wrapper{
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.element{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.title{
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.description{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#speedometer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

canvas{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <section class="ui-section">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="title">
        Speedometr
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <svg id="speedometer" viewbox="0 0 300 300"></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank @Ruben, it helped but, I want to avoid a hard code, so how should I calculate values for animations translation ? return `
            translate(158 176) ???
            rotate(${angleDegrees + 180} 3.5 7) // 3.5 ? 7? 
            translate(0 132)
          `;

Comment: 158 and 176 are approximately equal to the translate on foreground, 3.5 and 7 are half of the size of the triangle marker (which is 7.5*14px) to put the rotation point in the centre, and 132 is outerRadius + some padding. All other values in your example are hardcoded, so in the future, I recommend using variables for them in your question too

Comment: Don't use the same question to ask a massive follow-up like this. You completely altered the nature of the question, rendering it useless to anyone who has the same question you originally did. StackOverflow is not meant to help only you. It's based on the idea that if you have a question, other people will too, and we build a system of questions and answers that will help other people too. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question.

Comment: If you post a new question in the next hour, I'd be happy to answer it

Comment: done, you can check it here. I will very much appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959415/d3-animate-group-by-path